# EmailID and UTM Parameters in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, web-analytics-connector

We are exporting a number of data views to our data warehouse. Our data team wants to be able to build some queries off the utm parameters we use on our emails.

I am able to do this using the API.

> /asset/v1/content/assets/{id}

However, to be able to automate this using Automation Studio and get it into a DE, I want to do it via a query.

I can't find anything in the docs that suggests this is possible. Is it?

Comment: You can use the API in a SSJS Query activity and upsert functions to insert in a DE.

Comment: Thanks Swati. I'm not familiar with SJSS, but I am decent at SQL and AMPscript, so I think I could figure it out. Would you mind providing some more details on how this would work? Or do you know of a good tutorial somewhere that steps through this particular scenario? Thanks

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/276268/retrieving-specific-email-object-using-ssjs This post might help you.

Answer (score 1):

This below code should give you a starting point.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
try {
var url = "https://mcjxbybvhgwn9kgd4wfv-kz3b6cq.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token"; 
var contentType = "application/json";
var payload = {
  "grant_type":"client_credentials",
  "client_id":"clientid",
  "client_secret":"clientsecret",
  "account_id":"MID"
};
  
var authRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
var statusCode = authRequest["StatusCode"];
var response = authRequest["Response"][0];
var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;

Write(accessToken);

var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];



  try{
    
    var url = "https://mcjxbybvhgwn9kgd4wfv-kz3b6cq.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/192981";
    var result = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
    var resultJson = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Stringify(result));
    Write((resultJson.Content);
  }
  catch (e) {

  e = Stringify(e).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')
 Write(e);
  
 } 

}
catch (e) {

  e = Stringify(e).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')
  Write(e);
}

</script>
```